# Animate center point of a view along a quadratic curve

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, animation, uiview

I have an app that stores user events in history. The events are added on one controller and are displayed in a controller within a different tab.

I would like to add a visual confirmation that an event has been recorded when a user taps "save button". I'm thinking of animating an interface element to move towards a tab bar controller that is responsible for showing records to the user.

[image: Animation curve]

In order to do so, I'm thinking of animating the center point of one of my interface elements. I know how to animate the center point, but it does so in a straight line. **How can I animate the center point in a more "curved" way?** Is there some way to accomplish this?

```
CGPoint center = self.ratingReticle.center;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn animations:^{
    //move the element offscreen
     self.ratingReticle.center = CGPointMake(260,500);

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    //hide the interace element once it is offscreen
    self.ratingReticle.alpha = 0;
    //restore the position of the interface element
    self.ratingReticle.center = center;

    [ UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        //fade the element back at the original position
        self.ratingReticle.alpha = 1;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];

}];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could that using Core Animation to move your object along a Bezier curve using `CAKeyFrameAnimation`.

```
-(void)animate
{
  CAKeyframeAnimation *posAnim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
  posAnim.path = [self bezierPath];
  [image.layer addAnimation:posAnim forKey:@"posAnim"];
}
```

where `bezierPath` returns a `CGPathRef` that suits your case.

Comment: Works fine, but just wondering, how can I change the animation duration?

Comment: @CEAFDC: `posAnim.duration = what_you_want_in_seconds;` (duration is part of the CAMediaTiming protocol adopted by CAAnimation).